# while inserting data to database using postman showing error in controller file

Tags: node.js, database, express, mongoose, insert

while using node.js i am not able to insert a data to database ,i am using express.js ,mongoose but getting error which i mentioned in code as comment

> Blockquote
>   error is 
>   Blockquote
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>       at insert (E:\node\website\controller\signup.js:5:25)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at Function.handle (E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
>       at router (E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>       at E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at expressInit (E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>       at E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at query (E:\node\website\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\query.js:45:5)
>   Blockquote 
>       //controller file named as signup.js

```
var express=require('express');
var post1=require('../model/singup')
var router=express.Router();
var insert=(req,res)=>{
    var name1= req.body.name;// error:name is not defined
    var email1= req.body.email;//error:email is not defined
    var password1= req.body.password;//error:password is not defined
    post1.create({
        name: name1,email:email1,password:password1
    },(err,result)=>{
        if(err){res.json({message:'error'
           })
        }
        else{res.json({message:'sucessful',result:result   
        })
     } 
})
}
router.post('/signup',insert);
router.get('/h',(req,res)=>{
    res.json({ 
        message:'insert'
    })
    console.log("insert");
    })
module.exports=router;
```

> Blockquote
>       //model file named as signup.js

```
require('../db');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise=require('bluebird');
var schema= new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{type:String,required:true},
    email:{type:String,required:true},
    password:{type:String,required:true},   
},
{timestamp:true});
module.exports=mongoose.model('post1',schema);
```

> Blockquote
>       //db.js file for database connection

```
var mongose=require('mongoose');
mongose.set('useNewUrlParser', 'true');
mongose.set('useCreateIndex', 'true');
mongose.set('useFindAndModify', 'true');
mongose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/website");
var db=mongose.connection;
db.on('error',console.error.bind(console,'connection error'));
db.once('open',(req,res)=>{
    console.log("connected with db!!!");
})
```

> Blockquote
>   //index.js

```
var app=require('./server')
var signup=require('./controller/signup')

 var session=require('express-session')
app.set('viewengin','ejs')
app.set('useNewUrlParser', 'true')
app.set('useUnifiedTopology', 'true')
app.use('/user',signup)
app.use(session({
    secret:'keyboard cat ',
    resave:false,
    cookies:{
        secrue:true
    },
}))
app.all('*',(req,res)=>{
    return res.json({status: 205,message: 'not found'});
})
var server=app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
req.end()
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are missing the [body-parser](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) middleware.

```sh
$ npm i body-parser
```

```js
var express=require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```